# multiple EJB jar file inside one EAR sharing the same persistence.xml

Tags: ejb-3.0, ear, jboss-4.2.x, persistence.xml

I am using JBoss 4.2.3 application server.

I have an EAR that currently contains 2 EJB (EJB 3) jars.

In the main EJB jar I have persistence.xml file with the data source configurations.

From the secondary EJB jar file I can successfully call the the EntityManager and read\write entities that are defined in the main EJB jar that contains the persistence.xml

If I try to put an entity in the secondary EJB jar module and then persist it via the EntityManager that uses the persistence unit from the main EJB I get an exception:

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: [ENTITY-CLASS-NAME] is not mapped

The solution I found is to create another persistence.xml in the secondary EJB module and change the persistence unit name.

I am not sure whether what I tried to do is correct? Can you please contribute whether I can have a way to share the same persistence.xml withing multiple EJB modules in the EAR (in a way I can have entities in both EJB modules)?

Answer (score 0):

Put the persistence.xml and entities into a JAR in the top-level lib/ directory of the EAR.  This should allow the persistence units to be used by all modules in the EAR.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. But, in that case the entities are still shared, I want to separate the entities to be relevant only for a specific EJB project I am using.

Comment: What I did is to add persistence.xml to the specific EJB project I want to also be able to see the entities.  Then I leave it mostly blank, but use the <jar-file> tag to point at my other EJB, e.g. <jar-file>Other-ejb.jar</jar-file>

Comment: @T.K. I know it's been a while but can you expound on your comment? Would the `<jar-file>Other-ejb.jar</jar-file>` be listed in application.xml as an ejb module in that case or just a java module?